# Approach for scraping a particular web page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I scraped the below to an extent:
http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Indonesia

I already have the headings for the operators. The format in which I need data is for each operator given a heading. I want to retrieve the table of information on in the page like `topup`, `days`, `data`, etc. using Beautiful Soup. The page has no unique attributes for table in each operator.
This is the code I Have written for Indonesia country to get their operators.

```
def indo(key):
page=requests.get(key);

text_data=page.text

soup=BeautifulSoup(text_data,'html.parser')

countryDict={}

operators=soup.select('h2 > span > b')

operators_list=[x.text.encode("utf-8")for x in operators]
operators_list=[operators_list[i] for i in range(1,len(operators_list))]
print operators_list
my_dict={};

for operator in operators_list:
    my_dict['operator']=operator;

    plan=soup.select('table > tr > td')
```

This is coming in format of td tags .How to make a dictionary of currency, data, bonuses, so that i can store it in a csv file after cleaning the data?

Comment: show us your code, what you have tried

Comment: StackOverflow is not an advice forum. Please show your work so we can help you fix your code.

Comment: I have edited my answer